# Why is the Picard-Fuchs equation for elliptic curves of second order?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, modular-forms

Consider the elliptic curve defined by a polynomial
$$
F(x,y,z) = t(x^3 + y^3 + z^3) - 3xyz
$$
If we consider the period integral
$$
\pi(t) = \int_{\gamma} \omega(t)
$$
where $\gamma$ is a $1$-cycle defined at and around $F$ for a variation of $t$. We can associate a second-order differential equation
$$
\frac{d^2 \pi(t)}{dt^2} + A(t)\frac{d\pi(t)}{dt} + B(t) = 0
$$
called the Picard-Fuchs equation. Why is this differential equation second order? Does this have something to do with the real dimension of the complex variety?

Comment: Why is this relevant? I am looking at https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~cschnell/pdf/notes/picardfuchs.pdf

Comment: So you want a general algebraic-geometry statement for (abelian) varieties ? On MO they have some cohomology explications. But to me this Picard-Fuchs equation is a statement about modular forms (ie. moduli space of elliptic curves) and it is explained [p.70](http://www.paris8.free.fr/The%201-2-3%20of%20Modular%20Forms%20-%20Bruinier,%20der%20Geer,%20Harder,%20Zagier.pdf) of 1-2-3 of modular forms.

Comment: Apparently, yes.

Comment: In the case of elliptic curve, the equation is of order $2$ is a property of the moduli space (the modular curve and its modular forms) and its genus.

Comment: @reuns Can you explain further? My main motivation for asking this question is understanding which order of pde I should expect for a flat family of varieties. For example, these types of computations show up when looking at Calabi-Yau manifolds.

Comment: Another explanation: Picard-Fuchs equations really come from the Gauss-Manin connection on the first de Rham cohomology of elliptic curves, and the latter has rank two.